# i am getting blank space in log file.how to remove blank space

Tags: java, csv

I am uploading csc file with some fields.after file upload when i click send button it will trigger a mail and i am adding some fields at the end of my csc file.But problem is there is a blank space between csv fields and Customer Data Upload..how to remove space.

This is my code.

```
    Util.updateLogFile(logFile, fileEntries[0], "Asset Data Upload" + 
                       String.valueOf(DATA_FILE_DELIMITTER) + "Customer Data Upload" + 
                       String.valueOf(DATA_FILE_DELIMITTER) + "Environment Data Upload" + 
                       String.valueOf(DATA_FILE_DELIMITTER) + "Association Data Upload", 
                       DATA_FILE_DELIMITTER);
```

Comment: An example with input and output data would be nice

Comment: @lara123 - can you please provide some more info?

Comment: Why in the call to updateLogFile the last parameter is DATA_FILE_DELIMITER ?